# React ExcelJS issue: The time column does not display the sum and average when multiple cells are selected in Excel

Tags: reactjs, excel, exceljs

Here is my function for generating the timesheet report.

```
generateExcelReport = () => {
        const { report } = this.state;

        const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
        const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Report');

        // Add a centered and formatted title
        const titleCell = worksheet.getCell('A1');
        titleCell.value = 'Detail Report';
        titleCell.font = { bold: true, size: 14 };
        titleCell.alignment = { horizontal: 'center' };
        worksheet.mergeCells('A1:M1');
        workbook.calcProperties.fullCalcOnLoad = true;

        // Add column headers and apply borders
        const headerRow = worksheet.addRow(['Sl.No','Employee Name','Activity', 'Activity Name', 'Job Number', 'Element','Sequence','Category','Start Date', 'Start Hour','End Date', 'End Hour', 'Hours']);
        headerRow.eachCell((cell) => {
            cell.font = { bold: true };
            cell.border = {
                top: { style: 'thin' },
                bottom: { style: 'thin' },
                left: { style: 'thin' },
                right: { style: 'thin' },
            };
            cell.alignment = { horizontal: 'center' };
        });

        // Add data rows and apply borders
        report.forEach((item, index) => {
            const dataRow = worksheet.addRow([
                index + 1,
                item.employeeName,
                item.activityType,
                item.activityName,
                item.jobNumber || 'N/A',
                item.elements || 'N/A',
                item.sequence || 'N/A',
                item.category || 'N/A',
                moment(item.timeSheet_startDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
                moment(item.timeSheet_startDate).format('HH:mm:ss'),
                moment(item.timeSheet_endDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY'),
                moment(item.timeSheet_endDate).format('HH:mm:ss'),
                moment.utc(item.timeDifference * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss'),
            ]);

            const hoursCell = dataRow.getCell('M');
            hoursCell.numFmt = '[hh]:mm:ss';

            dataRow.eachCell((cell) => {
                cell.border = {
                    top: { style: 'thin' },
                    bottom: { style: 'thin' },
                    left: { style: 'thin' },
                    right: { style: 'thin' },
                };
                cell.alignment = { horizontal: 'center' };
            });
        });

        // Calculate total hours
        let totalSeconds = 0;
        report.forEach((item) => {
            totalSeconds += item.timeDifference;
        });
        const totalDuration = moment.duration(totalSeconds, 'seconds');
        const totalHours = totalDuration.asHours();

        const totalHoursRow = worksheet.addRow(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Total Hours:', '']);


        const totalHoursCell = totalHoursRow.getCell('M');
        totalHoursCell.numFmt = '[h]:mm'; // Format the cell as time

        totalHoursCell.value = this.calculateTotalHours();

        totalHoursRow.eachCell((cell) => {
            cell.font = { bold: true };
            cell.alignment = { horizontal: 'center' };
        });

        worksheet.columns.forEach((column) => {
            column.width = 15; // Adjust this as needed
        });

        workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then(function (buffer) {
            saveAs(new Blob([buffer], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8" }), "report.xlsx");
        });

    };
```

I'm setting the time format for this column using 'moment.utc(item.timeDifference * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss'). Additionally, the format is configured in this manner:

```
const hoursCell = dataRow.getCell('M');
            hoursCell.numFmt = '[hh]:mm:ss';
```

After generating the Excel sheet, when I select the 'Hours' column to check the sum and average at the bottom of the Excel, it only displays the count. For example, in my Excel column, I'm only getting the count (9), and not the **sum and average**.

[image]